# Error when using "through" intermediate model with django-sortedm2m

Tags: django, database, sorting, django-models

Is it possible to define my own intermediate model with [sortedm2m](https://github.com/jazzband/django-sortedm2m) using through? In my case I have this model:

```
class Sample(models.Model):
   id_sample = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20)
   indexes = SortedManyToManyField(Index, through='SamplePoolIndexCand', blank=True)
   pools = SortedManyToManyField(Index, through='SamplePoolIndexCand', blank=True)
   gene_lists = SortedManyToManyField(Index, through='SamplePoolIndexCand', blank=True)
```

My intermediate table:

```
class SamplePoolIndexCand(models.Model):
    sample_id = models.ForeignKey(Sample, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pool_id = models.ForeignKey(Pool, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    index_id = models.ForeignKey(Index, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    gene_cand_list_id = models.ForeignKey(GeneCandList, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)                       

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("sample_id", "pool_id", "index_id", "gene_cand_list_id"),)
```

I got this error message:

```
AssertionError: The model is used as an intermediate model by '<class 'myproject.models.SamplePoolIndexCand'>' but has no defined '_sort_field_name' attribute
```

How can I solve this? I tried to add an ordering field in the intermediate table but I got the same error:

```
class SamplePoolIndexCand(models.Model):
    sample_id = models.ForeignKey(Sample, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pool_id = models.ForeignKey(Pool, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    index_id = models.ForeignKey(Index, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    gene_cand_list_id = models.ForeignKey(GeneCandList, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)                       
    sort_value = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["sort_value"]
        unique_together = (("sample_id", "pool_id", "index_id", "gene_cand_list_id"),)
```

I'm using Django version 3.1.7 and Python 3.8.10.

Comment: Try to add a `sort_value_field_name` in your m2m fields like: `indexes = SortedManyToManyField(Index, through='SamplePoolIndexCand', blank=True, sort_value_field_name='sample_id')` (for all m2m fields)

Comment: I tried it and the result was the same...